# Is it okay to talk to a dog?

Tags: dogs, health, communication, stress

I'm a divorced guy and I always talk to my dog. I praise him when he does something good and he likes it. When he does something bad, I talk to him in a strict voice. Also I tell him some stories time to time when I return from the office. Recently I caught myself on asking him a simple question and expecting an answer. Twice. This was not very polite, I'm trying to avoid that now. However, when I was talking about my private life and problems my pup looked very bored. So, now I have a question. Can my dog be stressed/depressed because he has to listen all the things I'm telling him?

Comment: The dog has no idea what you're talking about. Any interest it has will be in listening to what the human's noises say about your mood, and picking up one or two of the words that  it has learned matter to it (commands, "go out", "food"). That doesn't mean you can't talk to them -- I talk to my cats all the time, up to and including telling them stories -- but realize that you're doing it for yourself because that's part of how humans are sociable, not so much for the pet.

Comment: It's fine to talk to your dog however the dog won't know what you are talking about, they are dogs. They will pick up on your mood, if you are in a bad mood or feeling stressed/depressed, your dog will be the same way. Your mood will directly affect its. You can be telling him bad stuff but in a good voice, he will think it's good, they only listen to the tone of your voice

Answer (score 4):

It does not harm, but your dog has no clue what you're saying. They are, however, very adept at reading body language cues, so it can sometimes *seem* like they 'understand'. (They do, but they understand that you're sad, not your verbal explanation of why). Likewise, they can pick out your tone, and some words they will recognise and have formed an association with. (My dog knows 'walk' and 'bath' even when used discretely...)

The only thing you should avoid really, is mixing up 'nattering' with 'commands'. You want your dog to know that when you command 'SIT!' that means they need to pay attention and do what they're told. Hopefully though, you are already ensuring you use a proper commanding tone, and so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I talk to my pets all day! When I walk pass through them I call them by their nicknames and they are just happy. Our dogs love to hear our voices.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Pets, your post looks like an interesting and helpful yet an incomplete answer, could you please elaborate a bit more?